# Kafka Streams count throwing Exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Iam new to kafka streams and I have been working with ktable . Iam trying to detect dulicate events in kafka streams using the ktable and remove the duplicate events. As a inital step I tried building a simple Ktable but it throws error.

The code for creating ktable is shown below.

```
        AvroDeserializer  avroDeserializer = new AvroDeserializer();

        AvroSerializer avroSerializer = new AvroSerializer();

        Serde<GenericRecord> keySerde =  Serdes.serdeFrom(avroSerializer, avroDeserializer);
       
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();


        KStream<String, GenericRecord> records = builder.stream(topics, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), keySerde));

        records.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(String.valueOf(value.get("eventId")), value))
                .map((windowedUserId, count) -> new KeyValue<>(windowedUserId, count))
                .groupByKey()
                .count(Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("store")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                        .withValueSerde(Serdes.Long()))
                .toStream()
                .to("topic",Produced.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long()) );
```

But everytime I run this this throws following error.

```
2021-06-22 20:29:33.247 ERROR 14680 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [test-app-36b983af-8ed0-4a6b-be17-7a9ada214774] Encountered the following exception during processing and the registered exception handler opted to SHUTDOWN_CLIENT. The streams client is going to shut down now. 

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException while producing data to topic test-app-store-repartition. A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters (for example if using the DSL, `#to(String topic, Produced<K, V> produced)` with `Produced.keySerde(WindowedSerdes.timeWindowedSerdeFrom(String.class))`).
```

Can someone help me understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from `.groupByKey()` while producing to the `-repartition` topic, and it is using the default Serdes in your StreamsConfig

You would need to specify the Serdes for it using `.groupByKey(Grouped.with(keySerde, valueSerde))`, or modify your defaults in the StreamsConfig like the error says